What's Time Complexity O(n) or O(n^2)?
What is the algorithmic complexity of this code?
n*=n 
for(let i=0; i<=n; i++) { //something 
}

Specifically, I have a doubt if it is O(n) or O(n2). I have searched the internet and found both answers in forums and blogs, however I have not been able to find a similar example in bibliographic documentation. The closest thing I have found is in the book Introduction to Algorithms by Thomas H. Cormen, where there is an example that for goes up to √n and where it gives that its complexity is O(√n) If you graph the number of iterations of a for that goes up to 2*n you will realize that it is a linear function only that the slope changes, which can be said to be linear because the definition of Big-O itself includes a constant multiplied by g(x) for those cases but if the number of iterations grows quadratically then we could not say that it is linear. There is my big doubt

It's O(n). Complexity is determined when you look at the time spent when you increase n, so a function like T = f(n). What form does the function f take. So in your example if you increased n by k then the function would be linear. It does not matter that you first multiplied n by itself, it's still linear.

Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's a bit confusing regarding which value of n you're referring to, i.e., the original or the one after you square it. Since you have n*=n preceding the loop, if it's the original value of n you're dealing with, then the time complexity is O(n^2), else for the final value of n, then as Enigmativity's comment indicates, it's O(n) instead.

The body of your loop i s executed n+1 times, number if iterations is grown lineary. So the time complexity is O(n).

@Enigmativity but a for that goes from 0 to n*n is O(n^2) because for all possible n the number of iterations grows quadratically, what is the difference with this code?

@JohnOmielan This example is used more to explain the concept of input size then? Yes, I mean taking the n before n*=n as the input size

@Lenar - The for loop is O(n), but you could argue that the whole algorithm is O(n^2). Which bit are you asking about?

@Lenar For future reference, I suggest not reusing variable names like you did, as it can cause confusion as it did here. Instead, you could have had something like n2=n*n; and then for(let i=0; i<=n2; i++) { //something after that. Your request about the time complexity being O(n), or O(n^2) (or equivalently O(n2)), would be more unambiguous.

@Enigmativity My question is the complexity of the entire algorithm, and in what cases it could be O(n) or O(n^2), I would like you to clarify this definitively.
